# Support TLS for Community Edition

Tags: ssl, couchbase

I do not understand well, on [Which edition is right for me?](https://www.couchbase.com/products/editions).
It says that **Data transport over TLS** is supported for CE.
But little higher, **x.509 CA certificates for TLS & data service authentication** is only for EE.

Is it possible to sync clients and/or cluster nodes with SSL without certificate?

```
    couchbase-cli ssl-manage -c localhost --upload-cluster-ca rootCA.pem -u $CBU -p $CBP    
    ERROR: This http API endpoint requires enterprise edition
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apologies for the confusion here, there is TLS being applied at many levels of the Couchbase Data Platform.

The Community Edition supports encryption on the wire from a mobile device to the Couchbase Sync Gateway (or access to its REST API) since that is specifically meant to go over the public internet.

However, encryption on the wire from an application server to Couchbase Server or between Couchbase Server clusters is only supported in the Enterprise Edition.

The command you are referencing is to manage that second part.

You configure Sync Gateway to use TLS through its config file: https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/current/guides/sync-gateway/configuring-ssl/index.html

I hope that helps

Perry